# Unable to enter anything in input field on android device in NextJS app

Tags: android, next.js

I have a nextjs v10 app in production. It was working fine until some Android users recently complained that they have been unable to log in to the app. When they click on the input fields, the fields are highlighted but the keyboard does not open. It works fine on the Android emulators and some of the Android devices I have tested on. One of the customers said their device is Samsung Galaxy S24. I tried on s24 emulator on lambdaTest and it worked fine. The customer also tried Chrome and Samsung internet browsers. What might be the issue?

I tried emulators on appetize.io, BrowserStack and lambdaTest. I was not able to reproduce the issue anywhere. What could be the workaround now so customer can login to their account?

Here is my code:

```
<Form form={form} name="login" onFinish={onFinish} scrollToFirstError>
      <Form.Item
        name="email"
        rules={[
          {
            type: "email",
            message: "The input is not valid E-mail!",
          },
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your E-mail!",
          },
        ]}
        className={styles.formItem}
      >
        <Input
          placeholder={"email"}/>
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        name="password"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your password",
          },
        ]}
        className={styles.form_item}
      >
        <Input.Password
          placeholder="password" />
      </Form.Item>
      
      <Form.Item>
        <Button
          type="primary"
          htmlType="submit"
          className={`${styles.btn} ${styles.btnLogin}`}
        >
          Log in
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.